# Div containing an ul list does not have a width of 100% and it's inheriting the width of the shorter ul

Tags: css

I am trying to make a list of links, 6 links in a row.

The problem is I do not know how many links there will be. It could be only 2 or 25.

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/v8e3q/23/).

I must be doing something wrong with the css because:

1. If for example there are just 3 links, the border of the **.toplist** div is not covering the whole length of the **wrap** div.
2. Also, I can't get more then two divs aligning before a new row appears.
3. This is not that important, but In IE6, even if I use **overlow:auto** I don't see a background for my ul (if I set one), and also, if I set margin-bottom for the ul I don't see it.

Any ideas on whats wrong with the css?

Ty

Comment: You had set position of .toplist to absolute. If you dont do that you should be fine.
.toplist {
/*position:absolute;*/
top:0;
z-index:10;
border:1px solid #0f6;
padding:0 0 0.5em 1em
}

Comment: Yes, but I need that. The toplist have to have this position. Any workarounds?

Comment: use margin-top, margin-left etc, it is generally a bad idea to use absolute position anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your original fiddle to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8e3q/24/). Check this out:

```
.wrap {
width:960px; 
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid #000
}

.toplist {
border:1px solid #0f6;
padding:0 0 0.5em 1em
}

.toplist ul {
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.toplist ul li {
float:left;    
width:15%;
margin-right:1em;
line-height:1.4em;
border-bottom:solid 1px #222;
}
.toplist ul li a, .toplist ul li .cat {
display:block;
font-size:0.7em;
}

.content{
background-color:#FF2E2E;
color:#FFF;
margin-top:100px;
heyight:40px
}​
```

Hope this works. :) It works in **IE 6** too! :)

Comment: Ty so much, the wrap, does it matter if it's px or em? I saw you put pixels in. And basically I see you have changed the li lengths to percent. Why? Also, I really need the position absolute for the toplist.

Comment: Because, percent is based on the layout, and not the text size. Got it? It is better to stick to the layout of the page. i.e., Screen Resolution instead of text-size, as some people might use bigger screens. Hey, I checked it with IE 6 too! :) Mark my answer if it helps you! :)

Comment: I will, testing it now but it does not seem to work, I think it's because the absolute position of the .toplist div which I have to keep.

Comment: Okay, if you need the absolute positioning of the div, then give `width: 100%;` and give `margin: auto` to `.toplist ul` with a fixed width of `980px`. Try and let me know!

Comment: It works in IE 6! :D With `position: absolute` for the `div.toplist`

Comment: I need to test a bit more but I think it works, I put width 100% to .toplist, and removed the padding. And I put the padding to the ul instead.

Comment: Perfect! :) Thats the way to do! :)

Comment: In my actual website the IE6 does not show the margin-bottom of the ul. Let me edit the fiddle and put a link to the actual site, maybe you can take a look....

Comment: Okay. Please send the URL. Did you give `overflow: hidden` to the `.toplist ul`?

Comment: Did you give `overflow: hidden` to the `.toplist ul`?

Comment: yes, the blue color is the background of the ul with padding of 1em

Comment: Hey, wait a minute... Overflow hidden doesn't work on IE 6. So just for IE 6 alone, write this: `<br style="clear: both;" />` at the end of the `<ul>` before `</ul>`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but anyway, the IE6 is a minor problem, not sure anyone is still using it. :)

Comment: Sure, an upvote would be awesome, thanks for accepting. BTW, did you use `<br style="clear: both;" />`, which works in IE 6?

Comment: I knew about this fix but I think it keeps the doc from validating

Comment: Kind of... but see you can use this way: `<!--[if IE 6]>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<![endif]-->`
Valid XHTML! :P